# How to hide negative part in scatter plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, scatter-plot

I have scatter plot as shown below I have to remove negative part of this scatter plot I tried it using

```
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
```

But it is throwing `error property 'orthogonalCoordinateDecimal' not found on object 'x'`. I have my code snippet as follows

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;

// Configure x-axis

CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.title = @"";
x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
x.titleOffset = 0.0f;
x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
x.majorGridLineStyle=gridLineStyle;
x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you get your code from? What is CPTAxis class?

Comment: i got this from this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2

Comment: now i changed that CPTAxis to CPTXYAxis and the error has gone but its  not removing the negative part

Comment: well update your question then if you have some new info now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this settings to limit axis ranges. It may help you too.

```
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)barChart.defaultPlotSpace;
    [plotSpace setYRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(500.0f)]];
    [plotSpace setXRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(12.0f)]];
```